# Easiest way to hack Drupal 6.22 installation for security audit

Tags: security

I am doing a security audit for a client.  Their installation is Drupal 6.22.  I need to show them it's unsafe.  What is the easiest way to hack it as an example?

I would need to directly show them the steps, so it must be quite detailed instructions.  They have the following modules installed:

1. Administration menu
2. Color
3. Comment
4. Database logging
5. Help
6. PHP filter
7. Taxonomy
8. Update status
9. Masquerade
10. CKEditor
11. AES

Here are some common settings:

1. Server      Apache/2.2.3
2. MySQL database  5.0.77
3. PHP     5.2.17
4. update.php  Protected
5. File system Writable
6. register_globals    Disabled

Answer (score 4):

The question you're asking is pretty impossible to answer. If you know Drupal and/or web security then you'll know the answer already. If you don't then the answer is too long to put into a Stack Exchange comment.

Here are some articles about how I have gained knowledge of web application security and how I perform a security audit of a Drupal site:

- [How to become a Drupal security expert](http://drupalscout.com/knowledge-base/how-become-drupal-security-expert)
- [Steps to a Drupal Security Review](http://drupalscout.com/knowledge-base/steps-drupal-security-review)

I agree with Ivan Alfaro that the security_review module is a good start. Many of the elements that the security_review module audits can be audited from outside a site, so you could look at what it does and see if you can do similar things.

Comment: I went through the few modules recommended in your link and they were not able to identify any problems.  I am going to start reading Cracking Drupal soon...

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to identify potential vulnerabilities is to install the [Security review](http://drupal.org/project/security_review) module.

Comment: This is definitely an easy solution, but not a complete one. Thanks for recommending it!